# How to update data of github file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, git, github

I've uploaded a document.json file on my github ac and
to get data from the file I'm using javascript

```
$http({
    method: "GET",
    url: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/username/database/master/document.json',
    obj
  }).then(function mySuccess(response) {
    console.log(response);
  }, function myError(response) {
   console.log(response.statusText);
  });
```

what should I do if I want to write data in the file??
how to make post request??
thanks in advance... :)

Comment: Github.com is not a hosting website. If you want to update the file, you have to commit an updated version (or perhaps use there API to create this commit). No POST requests will work.

Comment: if I upload this file on any hosting website then can I use get put 0r post request?

Comment: To any hosting website, I don't think so but there is some websites specialised in json hosting (like for example https://jsonblob.com/ )